# Random number generation in C vs Java

Tags: java, c, math, random

I was curious to know why `random_number=a+rand()%b;` in C produces a random number between a and b (non-inclusive of b). But in Java this code will not work. I understand that the correct way to do this in Java is `random_number=a+(Math.random()*(b-a));` but I was curious to know why there is a difference? Isn't it the same operation mathematically? I also understand that the return types are different for the random functions, but how does this difference explain the difference in output? Sorry if this seems like a trivial question but I was curious nonetheless.

Comment: Why isn't `Java` exactly the same as `C`?

Comment: `rand` generates an integer between `0` and `RAND_MAX`. `Math.random` generates a double between `0` and `1`. Hence the different expressions. Btw, `a+rand()%b` generates a random number between `a` and `a+b` (non-inclusive). You meant to write `a+rand()%(b-a)`.

Comment: `a+rand()%b` would not work. Maybe you're thinking of `a+rand()%(b-a)`. Also the C rand() returns a random integer while Java Math.random() returns a float between 0 and 1.

Comment: Your inital assumption is wrong: the range is rather [a..(a+b-1)]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference lies in what each random generator does.

In Java, [`Math.Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) returns a pseudo-random number of the range `0` (inclusive) through `1` (exclusive).  So it must be scaled up by `b - a`, the width of the range, then shifted by `a`, the start of the range.

In C, [`rand()`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rand+3) returns numbers in the range `0` to `RAND_MAX` (my `RAND_MAX` is `32767`), so `%b` is used to control the width of the range, and the start of the range is shifted by `a`.

Answer (score 2):

One can, of course use java.util.Random's `nextInt()` or `nextInt(int n)` method to more exactly mimic the C scheme.  `nextInt()` is almost exactly the same as `rand()` (though hopefully better distributed) while `nextInt(int n)` effectively subsumes the `%n` calculation.

Answer (score 0):

*In java it is `nextInt()`*

```
int nextInt(int n)
```

**This function returns random number between 0 to n**

*In C it is `rand()`*

```
int rand(void)
```

**This function returns an integer value between 0 and RAND_MAX.**